# Resize a running Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am facing a challenge to scale an existing Amazon EC2 instance from `t2.micro` to `t2.medium`.

Can someone suggest me about the best practice to do this, without losing any data which stored on the `t2.micro` instance?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Stop the EC2 instance.
2. Change the instance type (e.g. t2.micro to t2.medium).
3. Start the EC2 instance.

*Note: You will not lose the data.*

When you stop an EC2 instance, what AWS does is the following:

1. It (AWS) shuts down the machine. So, the CPU, RAM, etc, are available for someone else to use.
2. It preserves the hard disk(s). Hence, your data is always with you.
3. In the shut-down state, you can change the machine type. This only logically links the CPU, RAM, etc. When you start the machine, AWS allocates the actual machine to you and connects your hard disk to that machine.

*Note: In the shut-down state, you don't pay for CPU, RAM etc but since you keep the disk, you continue to pay a little amount towards the disk.*

If you do not want to use the machine in the future select option menu > Instance State > Terminate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, **stop the EC2 instance, change its instance type and start it**.

*Note: Stopping and restarting the instance erases any data on instance store volumes. Be sure that you back up any data on the instance store volume that you want to keep. Instance store volumes are different from EBS volumes.*

Reference: [Back Up an Instance Store Volume to EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/back-up-instance-store-ebs/)

Comment: @Rajesh The t2 family does not have any instance store, so don't panic!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein True, I just shared this information so that If Rajesh uses some other EC2 instance type in the future, he keeps this piece of information in mind.